# Java: cannot call a function with parameters

Tags: java, function

I am creating a little program to find the largest number in an array. The problem is that when I call my function to check for the largest value it says that it expects a class, but that doesn't really make sense for me.

Sorry for my beginner question, but I couldn't find any help elsewhere.

Here is my current code:

```
package challenge;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Challenge {
    public static int findMax(int arr[], int size) {
        int maxValue = arr[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(arr[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numbers[] = new int[300];
        System.out.println("Enter data: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            numbers[i] += input;
        }
        int maxValue = findMax(numbers[], numbers.length);
        System.out.println("The largest value in the array: " + maxValue);

    }
}
```

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: I'd advise you to write `int[] numbers` (instead of `int numbers[]`), as that cleary conveys that you've got a variable named `numbers` of type `int[]` (integer-array). That does *not* solve your problem, but you'll be more likely to spot the error once you changed that ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
int maxValue = findMax(numbers[], numbers.length);
```

to this

```
int maxValue = findMax(numbers, numbers.length);
```

when you pass array to a method you should not include `[]` brakets.you should pass the name of array `numbers` not `numbers[]`

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot, never knew that arguments require only the data type names.